# How to debounce multiple inputs using a loop?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created lots of text inputs using a loop:

```
lapply(1:5, function(x){textInput(paste0('text',x), label = '')})
```

I have now `input$text1`, `input$text2`, `input$text3` etc...
How can I debounce them using a loop?
The idea is to now have objects named `debounced_text1`,`debounced_text2`, etc..

Below does not work:

```
lapply(1:5, function(x){
  
  assign(paste0('debounced_text',x),debounce(r = input[[paste0('text',x)]], millis = 1000), envir = .GlobalEnv) 
  
})
```

I have also tried using get()

```
debounce(r = get(paste0('input$text',x), millis = 1000)
```

but using get() that way does not work.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debounce` expects a reactive expression - please check the following.

*Debounce each input separately:*

```
library(shiny)

textInputIDs <- paste0('text', 1:5)

ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(textInputIDs, function(x){textInput(x, label = x)}),
  textOutput("debouncedText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lapply(textInputIDs, function(x){assign(paste0("debounced_", x), debounce(r = reactive({input[[x]]}), 1000), envir = .GlobalEnv)})
  
  output$debouncedText <- renderText({
    paste("User input:", debounced_text1(), debounced_text2(), debounced_text3(), debounced_text4(), debounced_text5(), sep = ", ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another approach is to wrap all inputs in a single `reactive` which returns a `list()` and debounce only this reactive.

*Debounce bundled inputs:*

```
library(shiny)

textInputIDs <- paste0('text', 1:5)

ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(textInputIDs, function(x){textInput(x, label = x)}),
  textOutput("debouncedText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  debouncedInputs <- debounce(r = reactive({lapply(textInputIDs, function(x){input[[x]]})}), 1000)
  
  output$debouncedText <- renderText({
    paste("User input:", paste(debouncedInputs(), collapse = ", "))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```